# Variables declared in constructor conflicting with class properties

Tags: object, actionscript, orientation, scope

I'm creating a button in ActionScript by extending flash.display.SimpleButton

The button doesn't behave as expected, however, when I declare certain variables in the constructor which also happen to exist as properties in the SimpleButton class. They appear to conflict..

Why is this? Shouldn't the locally declared variables be allowed to co-exist with similarly named class properites?

Snippet below might better illustrate the issue:

```
public class MyButton extends SimpleButton{

    public function MyButton(/*..*/){

        var upState:ButtonDisplayState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/));
        var downState:ButtonDisplayState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);      
        var overState:ButtonDisplayState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);      
        var hitTestState:ButtonDisplayState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);       

        super(upState, overState, downState, hitTestState);

   }

}
```

The API docs are here (look for upState for example): http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html#upState

Thanks,

Aodh.

Comment: Just to clarify, renaming the variables to e.g. up, down, hit etc. works, but I'm curious as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redeclare already existing variables, local or not. The only place where you can do something like this is method parameters, where you can have same parameter names as local / class variables.

Why don't you just pass in those states to the constructor directly like:

```
super(new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/)), new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/)), new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/)), new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/)));
```

or alternatively just set them directly after calling `super();` like this:

```
upState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/));
downState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);      
overState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);      
hitTestState = new ButtonDisplayState(/*..*/);
```

Comment: Ok I just did a test where I redeclared a class variable in the constructor and when I trace the value, I get the expected results i.e. locally redeclared variable doesn't have any impact on the class declared variable. I also did a test for properties with the same result..

Comment: Did you put them *after* the `super();`?

Comment: I wrote a quick test case and set variables both before and after calling super. In both cases, neither the super nor sub class variables interfere with each other?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you, but even if you somehow manage to make it work, I _strongly_ discourage you from having variables named in the same way, but doing different things in a subclass.

Comment: Just to clarify, the variables are declared in the constructor, so as far as I'm aware, and the reason why I posted this question, is that their scope should thus be limited to the constructor and not anything outside of it?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but their names still can't clash with properties inherited from anywhere else as those are also available in the scope of your constructor.

Comment: But surely all variables or properties declared at class level are available in the scope of any function within that class? I would have thought it perfectly legitimate to declare a variable within a function and not have it affect anything outside of that function?

Comment: The answer to your first question is mainly yes, although there might be some edge cases like anonymous / inline event handlers and such which don't inherit the scope of the parent class, but any properly declared class method certainly does. How would you change anything inside the class if the methods in it wouldn't be able to access the properties implicitly?

Comment: I'm not arguing that this is a good thing and in answer to your question: you might qualify with super in this case, to disambiguate. The issue is that the super class appears to be dictating how I name my variables in function scope, which seems wrong to me...unless that isn't the problem..

Comment: That's right, the language could work in a way that you need to use super for anything inherited, but that would be really tedious. So yes, the super class and the entire inheritance chain does dictate your local variable naming, but that's the price for the convenience that you don't have to explicitly type super every time.

Comment: super to disambiguate is what I meant. But with regard to the answer, it only seems to dictate in this one case as mentioned earlier, my test cases suggest otherwise..so what's going on with the SimpleButton class or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, SimpleButton being special in this case is weird and completely beyond me :) Maybe reformulate your question a bit so someone else can shed light on it?